# Replace text if in parentheses and specific character before

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript, I am trying to replace text if its in parentheses and the the parentheses has a specific character (`A`) before it.

A string can look like this:

```
A(This text) should (say) hello.
```

Here `A(This text)` should be replaced with `You`, but `(say)` should not be replaced at all, because it does not have the character `A` before it. Also the character `A` has to be in uppercase.

I have tried with regex but I find it very hard to understand. Right now I can only remove `A` and then replace whats inside parentheses, but this also removes other text inside parentheses that does not have `A` before them.

This is what I got:

```
const string = "A(This text) should (say) hello."

function runIt() {
 const replace = string.replace(/ *\A() */g, "You") //Removes "A"
 let replace2 = replace.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, " ") //"Removes all text inside all parentheses

 console.log(replace2) //Result is: "You should hello.", it should say: "You should (say) hello.
}

runIt();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
\bA\([^()]+\)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/xJ6RYy/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A                        'A'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^()]+                   any character except: '(', ')' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

**JavaScript code**

```js
const string = "A(This text) should (say) hello."

function runIt(string) {
  let replace2 = string.replace(/\bA\([^()]+\)/g, 'You')
  console.log(replace2)
}

runIt(string)
```